# Hibernate errors after changing database "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am creating web application in Spring andI was using local MySql database and everything was good.
But I decided to use online free database.

when i am trying to execute any JpaRepository query, I got error like this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '?3_4_0_, employee0_.`permission` as permissi4_4_0_,
>   employee0_.`ulica` as ulica5' at line 1

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@Table(name = "`Pracownicy`")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "`id`")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "`Imię`")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "`Nazwisko`")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "`Ulica`")
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "`Miasto`")
    private String town;

    @Column(name = "`Kod_pocztowy`")
    private String zipCode;

    @Column(name = "`Permission`")
    private String permission;

    @Column(name = "`id_aktywnego_zamówienia`")
    private Integer activeOrder;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "employee")
    private EmployeeLogin employeeLogin;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "employee")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Any ideas why?

These are my propertise.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://sql2.freesqldatabase.com:3306/sql2270378?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username= *********
spring.datasource.password= **********
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: It might have something to do with all the backticks(right name?) you have in the names of your columns and your table (but I'm not certain).

Comment: Like @Slaw pointed, I think the problem is in your column names. Try removing those ` ` from the column names. Also, unless you want to override default column naming, it's not mandatory at all to use `@column` anotations. JPA automatically asigns columns (check your declared attributes are in the same order as in your DB). Also try to remove the  ` ` from `@table name`

Comment: I was trying without this all ` ` and the result was the same.